# Set worker role monitoring level in ServiceConfiguration

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles, azure-diagnostics

I cannot change the monitoring level of my deployed worker role to **Verbose**:

[image: Worker Role monitoring level]

I get the following error:

[image: Portal error]

[image: Error details]

**Question:**

Is it not possible for me to set the monitoring level in the `ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg` file and then redeploy the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. In fact, I don't think the monitoring configuration is even stored in the `ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg` file. I updated the monitoring configuration from `MINIMAL` to `VERBOSE` and it updated successfully. After that I download the configuration file and it was exactly the same as I uploaded when I created the deployment.

My guess is that there's another set of REST API which is responsible for monitoring configuration though I could not find the documentation for that.

Comment: What is the "minimal" vs. "verbose" setting in the portal for?  I wouldn't think that is related to the Windows Azure Diagnostics settings in the .cscfg.

Comment: No it's not (at least that's what I think). By changing from minimal to verbose, I saw some additional tables in my storage account which were not there previously: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GhRUB.png

Comment: So I guess the question now is what are those tables for?  Time to go inspecting!  :)

Comment: After you switch to "Verbose", go to the Monitor tab then click on Add Metrics at the bottom.  You'll now be able to add many more metrics and where available under "Minimal".